# How many ways to seat $8$ of $31$ people on a boat with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

**Task condition:**

On each side of the boat should be seating for $4$ persons. How many ways you can select for this boat, if there are $31$ candidates, with ten people who want to sit on the left side of the boat, twelve who want to sit on the right side, and nine indifferent as to where they sit?

**I have no thoughts**

Comment: I'm sorry  that you have no thoughts. Try breaking up the problem into parts that are more managable. Feel free to share your progress.

Comment: It's not a standart situation with combinations. 9 people who indifferent as to where sit can be on the left side and on the right side. I think it's possible to break up situtatuion when 9 people don't sit at all, some sit on the left side, some on the right side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing too difficult about it, only it is tedious. Fill up $0$ through $4$ "specialists" on their favoured sides and fill the balance from the 9 others, e.g. if you choose 2 specialists for left and 3 for right,

$${10\choose2}{12\choose3}{9\choose2}{7\choose1}$$ which generalises to

$$\sum_{l=0}^4 \sum_{r=0}^4{10\choose l}{12\choose r}{9\choose 4-l}{5+l\choose 4-r}$$